Manga where a guy teleports into his favorite game as the main villain and helps shogun-era Japan get rid of a virus
I saw it like a year ago and I can't get it out of my hand for some reason.
He helps shogun-era Japan to get rid of a virus that's gonna wipe them out or something. I really don't remember the exact thing, but if anyone knows the name, please let me know.

Is this a manga or an anime? You used both tags.

i have no idea!

Amatsuki

Tokidoki is a Japanese high school student who, when he fails his history class, is sent to a high-tech history museum that virtually recreates the Edo period to do make-up work. However, what was supposed to be a simple school project becomes much more complicated when he's attacked by two supernatural beings known as "the nue" and "the yakou" and loses the vision in his left eye. After he's saved from the nue by a girl named Kuchiha, he realizes that he's no longer wearing the simulation goggles, and is trapped in the virtual Edo. Meanwhile, in the real world, Sensai Corporation, the virtual reality company who made the virtual museum Tokidoki is trapped in, is seen throughout the story. - Wikipedia



oh its not that the game is like a fantasy game with magic and stuff
